# Stripe promise pending even though it's async/await

Tags: node.js, vue.js, stripe-payments

I have a separate file created to facilitate stripe-based functions called stripe.js.

In this file I want to create a function that retrieves session object, so I initialize stripe with my test key and create function that I export as so:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('my_stripe_key_here');


export async function obtainSession(sid) {
    return await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(sid);
}
```

Now in the App.vue I first import the function and try to use it:

```
import { obtainSession } from "./stripe/stripe";

let session = obtainSession(this.session_id)
             .then(session=> {
               return session
             });
console.log(session)
```

And all I get is a pending promise in the console (Promise < pending >)

I've tried for a few days and tested different approaches from stackoverflow and elsewhere but I cannot seem to get this promise resolved. I am using a valid and existing session ID with no result.

Can anybody tell me what's the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
let session = obtainSession(this.session_id)
         .then(session=> {
           return session
         });
```

Doing this doesn’t mean this will return after the `then`- it will return immediately with the Promise returned by obtainSession. The continuation will also run once the promise resolves, but that return is basically meaningless in this flow.

You will have to await this call. Or if you log inside the `then`  you’ll see the result.

You could consider retrieving this and awaiting inside `mounted` or similar, or have the code set `session` as a module variable. But in all cases this is going to be something that returns a promise you have to wait for outside of tHat assignment.